# How to do bootstrap initialize hibernate in a maven web project?

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

How to do bootstrap initialize hibernate in a maven web project?

```
public class HibernateTest {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        UserData us1 = new UserData();
        us1.setfName("amit");
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

It cannot be done by the above code, where UserData is an entity.

Comment: Did you read the furry manual? http://hibernate.org/orm/documentation/5.2/

Answer (score 0):

First declare dependency for hibernate in pomm.xml:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

Next create configuration file `hibernate.cfg.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
 "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/UserDB</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>

        <property name="connection.pool_size">10</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>

        <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

        <!-- <property name="FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS">0</property> -->

        <!-- Mapping files -->
        <mapping class="com.stackoverflow.model.Person" />
        <mapping class="com.stackoverflow.model.Phone" />

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

If you have your entities you should list them in tag `<mapping class="pathToEntity">`.

Next in main method :

```
    // A SessionFactory is set up once for an application!
            final StandardServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
                    .build();
            try {
                SessionFactory sessionFactory = new MetadataSources(registry).buildMetadata().buildSessionFactory();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // The registry would be destroyed by the SessionFactory, but we had
                // trouble building the SessionFactory
                // so destroy it manually.
                StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(registry);
                System.out.println("Exception\n" + e);
            }
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
```

Here you create `Sessionfactory` and get current `Session` object to be able to query database.

Comment: thank you for the answer Jay, but can you tell me as to where do i put the class with the main method to create session. Its a web project built in Maven.

Comment: is it even possible to a make a class with a main method since its a web project built in mven which has jsps with a main page. Hibernate is used only for a user to login or register.